# Should [shader], [pixel-shader], and [shading] be combined?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 3 tags that look related to me: [shader], [pixel-shader], and [shading]. It seems like these should all be the same thing. I could see a [vertex-shader] tag in addition to [pixel-shader] or [fragment-shader], but just [shader] and [shading] seem like the same thing as [pixel-shader].

Comment: I'll write up an actual answer later but I think these all have different uses. [shading] refers to lighting in general, [shader] is useful for questions about shader languages and concepts in general, regardless of the stage and [pixel-shader], [vertex-shader], etc for stage specific questions. Maybe these need better tag wikis to clarify the differences.

Comment: I think better tag wikis would help. I'm still left wondering what the difference between [shading] and [lighting] is given your explanation.

Comment: I don't think there is one. [That was one of my examples of possible synonyms during the private beta](http://meta.computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/84/16) (which I totally forgot to revisit). That should probably be discussed in a separate meta post though.